# How do I match all the subscripted terms in Times?

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose I have an expression:
$W = A_{i,p,q...}\,\, a_ia_ja_ka_l...$,
where $A_{i,p,q...}$ is an expression that does not depend on $a$, the indexes $i,j,k,l,p,q...$ are integers and all the integers within $a_i$ the terms must be different. The number of the variables $a$ in the term can be arbitrary, but more that one.

I need to process those the terms with a function, that takes as arguments the coefficient $A_{i,p,q...}$ and a list of the indexes ${i,j,k,l...}$.

Thus I wrote:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[A_ Subscript[a, n1_] Subscript[a, n2_] /; 
    FreeQ[A, a] && n1 != n2] := reduction[A, {n1, n2}];
f[A_ Subscript[a, n1_] Subscript[a, n2_] Subscript[a, n3_] /; 
    FreeQ[A, a] && n1 != n2 != n3] := 
  reduction[A, {n1, n2, n3}];
f[A_ Subscript[a, n1_] Subscript[a, n2_] Subscript[a, n3_] Subscript[
     a, n4_] /; FreeQ[A, a] && n1 != n2 != n3 != n4] := 
  reduction[A, {n1, n2, n3, n4}];
f[A_] := reductionError[A]
```

where `reduction` is one of my functions.

Everything works works for a term up to four variables, obviously, the question is, how to generalize it to an arbitrary number? I cannot use `Coefficient`, as I don't know the values of the subscripts.

**edit:**

One may think about a function like this:

```
f[A_ B_ /; FreeQ[A, a]] := 
  reduction [A, # /. Subscript[a, j_] :> j & /@ List @@ (B)];
```

However it fails on complex expressions:

```
f[(A + B) Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[a, 3]
   Subscript[a, 6]/8]
```

returns:

```
reduction[1/8, {A + B, 1, 2, 3, 6}]
```

Comment: Your edit invalidates everything you wrote so far! It's clear that as soon as you put anything else than subscripts in your call, it's not a multiplication of subscripts any more and your function-pattern does **probably** no longer match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you don't have to do anything at all. Your pattern says *a multiplication of subscripted `a`'s that should not have the same subscript*. Have you thought about happens *if* they have the same subscript?

```
test[x Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[a, 1]]//FullForm
(* List[1,3,4,5][Times[x,Power[Subscript[a,1],2],Subscript[a,2]]] *)
```

Note the `Power` in the output. Therefore, as soon as you have two identical subscripts in your call, it's not a multiplication of subscripts anymore and it is basically enougth to say (don't forget to `ClearAll[f]` before you do):

```
f[Times[A_, t : Subscript[a, _] ..] /; FreeQ[A, a]] := 
 With[{subs = {t}[[All, 2]]}, reduction[A, subs]]
```

The hardest part is to see that `t` is the *sequence* of subscripted variables and by putting `{}` around it you can turn it into a list and extract all subscripts.

Btw, using global variable `a` in this definition and using `Subscript` at all cries for trouble.

Comment: Yes, this works! Of course, I substituted the local variable to `a` here for simplicity of the code. Why the subscripts are evil?

Comment: Evaluate this `Subscript[y, 1] = 3` and then try to clear the variable again. If you know how to do it, you are prepared to use `Subscript`.

Comment: I have checked your expression on the most of my cases, and it matched perfectly always. The variables $a_i$ will never get a numerical value, so I on the safe side.